# Tring to get nedb to import in a Svelte component

Tags: electron, svelte, nedb

I have a basic Electron/Svelte app and I'm trying to add database functionality using nedb. If I use `let Datastore = require("nedb")` I get an error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". The best advice I could find was to use import but using `import Datastore from 'nedb'` I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: util is not defined at main.js:6". thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. nodeIntegration needed to be set to true in the parameters for new BrowserWindow()

```
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 900,
        height: 680,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
          }
    });
```